# Apache Beam Global Counting

Tags: java, apache-beam

I am trying to understand the best way of solving the following:

As simple example scenario, I have a file which describes a test name and if its execution passed (true/false).

```
test-scenario,passed
--------------------
testA,true
testB,false
```

Using apache beam I can read, parse the file into `PCollection<TestDetails>` and then using subsequent transforms write all test details which have passed to one set of files and likewise for those tests which failed.

After writing the above files I would finally like to generate some counts regarding: the total number of file records processed, number tests that passed, number test that failed and write these details to a single file.

Should I use a combine global for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, you can use Beam Metrics (please, see the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#metrics)). It provides counters, that can be used for the needs you described above, and then metrics can be fetched once your pipeline is finished. Please, take a look on [this example](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#using-metrics). Also, Beam allows to export metrics into external sink, if it's more convenient.